# RoR 3.0: rake db:create syntax error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, syntax-error, ruby-1.9.2

*** I'm going to learn Rails 3.1 better before I continue with this.  Thanks for your help, everyone: I learned a lot! ***

I'm trying to create an online portfolio based on Gullery, but I'm stuck at the very beginning: I can't create a database.  When I run 'rake db:create', I get the following error:

> rake aborted!
>
> C:\Sites\gullery/RakeFile:14: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

When I run a full trace, I get this:

> C:\Sites\gullery>rake db:create --trace
>
> rake aborted!
>
> C:/Sites/gullery/Rakefile:14: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_e
>   nd
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_
>   module.rb:25:in `load'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_
>   module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
>   cation.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
>   cation.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
>   cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
>   cation.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
>   cation.rb:65:in `block in run'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
>   cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
>   cation.rb:63:in `run'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
>    `'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `load'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `'

When I searched for "syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end" on Google, the answers suggested that I missed an end somewhere.  Unfortunately, I don't have the experience to know which file is missing one.  Is that even the right problem?  If so, where should I look?  If not, what's actually going on?

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.0, Ruby 1.9.2, and mySQL.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The contents of C:\Sites\gullery\Rakefile:

```
    # Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
    # for example lib/tasks/switchtower.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

    require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

    require 'rake'
    require 'rake/testtask'
    require 'rdoc/task'
    RDoc::Task.new do |rdoc|

    require 'tasks/rails'

    # Fail if unit tests fail
    task :default => [:test_units, :test_functional]
```

EDIT 2: Adding an "end" to the Rakefile eliminates the syntax error, but I the database still won't work.

The new Rakefile:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/switchtower.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
RDoc::Task.new do |rdoc|
end

require 'tasks/rails'

# Fail if unit tests fail
task :default => [:test_units, :test_functional]
```

And the new error/trace:

```
C:\Sites\gullery>rake db:create --trace

WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/tas
k' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rak
e/rdoctask.rb

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rdoc/task.rb:30: warning: already ini
tialized constant Task

rake aborted!

Don't know how to build task 'db:create'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_
manager.rb:49:in `[]'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:115:in `invoke_task'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `each'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block in top_level'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:88:in `top_level'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:66:in `block in run'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:63:in `run'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
 `'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `load'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `'
```

Comment: You definitely want to show us contents of `C:\Sites\gullery/RakeFile` or to check what's cracked on 14th line by yourself.

Comment: Is that what the 14 means? That helps to know!  I'll add the contents of the RakeFile above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Rails 3.1 and my Rakefile looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

V0100::Application.load_tasks
```

V0100 is my application name, corresponds to your "gullery".

Comment: That's what my rakefile for another application looks like, too.  I bet that's a clue, but I think I'm going to abandon this particular project.  I need to learn Rails 3.1 properly before I try to figure out earlier versions. :)